# Need to run bash script in aws datapipeline

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

i need to call the ruby file using the bash script in aws data pipeline

i have tried using shell command activity with command args

## json file

```
> {
>       "objects": [
>         {
>           "terminateAfter": "1 Hours",
>           "id": "ResourceId5",
>           "schedule": {
>             "ref": "ScheduleId4"
>           },
>           "name": "Resource1",
>           "logUri": "s3://pipeline_test/output1/",
>           "type": "Ec2Resource"
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "ActivityId1",
>           "schedule": {
>             "ref": "ScheduleId4"
>           },
>           "name": "Shell",
>           "command": "bash -lc 'cd ~/pipeline_test/inputs/ && ruby sample.rb'", # bash command script path for ruby file
>           "runsOn": {
>             "ref": "ResourceId5"
>           },
>           "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
>           "output": {
>             "ref": "DataNodeId3"
>           }
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "DataNodeId3",
>           "schedule": {
>             "ref": "ScheduleId4"
>           },
>           "directoryPath": "s3://pipeline_test/output/",
>           "name": "Output",
>           "type": "S3DataNode"
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "Default",
>           "scheduleType": "timeseries",
>           "name": "Default",
>           "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
>           "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole"
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "ScheduleId4",
>           "startDateTime": "2013-08-01T00:00:00",
>           "name": "schedule",
>           "type": "Schedule",
>           "period": "20 Minutes",
>           "endDateTime": "2013-08-03T00:00:00"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
```

## sample.rb

```
f = File.open('text.txt', 'a+')
old_out = $stdout
$stdout = f
puts "Start time #{Time.now}"
puts "Welcome"
puts "End time #{Time.now}"
f.close
```

i dont know how to give the s3 path ("command": "bash -lc 'cd ~/pipeline_test(bucket_name)/inputs/ && ruby sample.rb'",
)

i am getting the script exit status 1

Help me out to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to have a wrapper shell script, something like below which invokes "sample.rb".

`$INPUT1_STAGING_DIR/sample.rb >> $OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR/output.txt`

Now instead of specifying "command", you could specify "Script Uri" pointing to the shell script in S3.

You should also enable "Stage = true", and make the Input datanode point to s3 folder containing sample.rb script.

More details on Staging can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-staging.html)

You will need to modify your sample.rb and have appropriate path like "$INPUT1_STAGING_DIR/text.txt" instead of giving "text.txt".

Hope this helps.